# Keep User History in Database

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I need to keep history of all the user activity on the server.
Activity involves User submission of data or one process.
The application needs to be designed for about 50k concurrent users.

What will be the best way to do so. If i create a new Table of History will it not get populated with rows to a huge number considering worst case scenarios ?

What is the best way to do so ?

Just for an analogy ; Consider a library with 50k concurrent users, i have to keep each user's history of book check-in check-out. Will it not get out of hands considering the number of users ?

Answer (score 0):

I think there are some missing details, what are you gonna do with this data? Can you hold it without indexes? or can you archive old data(old can be an hour ago).

SQLDB writing is pretty fast, but you design a 50K concurrent users activity, I recommend you to perform some in memory bucketing to the user activity and flush it to the db once a X activities.

Comment: Writing time to SQL is arguable but how much can SQL handle ?
The data needs to be saved and indexes are not important. This data will only be used when specifically querying about a user's History.

Comment: Build your worst case scenario and give it a try.

Comment: adding 50,000 rows a second ... will it exhaust the table ? And what about the select statement

Answer (score 0):

The best performing and most secure method is to implement history tables with **triggers** on the source table. This is the best way to implement both security and the actual business rules in one encapsulated object (the table). However, if you have no current practices for coding server-side routines, or you do not have a data dictionary system that will generate the code for you, then it may not be practical to go server-side for a single feature.

Implementing history tables in code has the usual benefit of keeping you in the language and habits you are most familiar with, but it means that you cannot allow access to your database except through your application. I cannot of course make a general rule here, this decision is best made by the design team based on the situation at hand and anticipated future needs.

Comment: What if you are the design team ?